# Limits and Logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I just realized the following. 
Let ($x_n$) be a series of numbers and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}{x_n} = x$. Then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \log_{y}{x_n} = \log_{y}{x}$. 
But what is the reason for this equation? Can anybody help me?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Important note: your sequence $x_{n}$ should be a sequence of *positive numbers* and the limit $x$ should also be a *positive* number, because the logarithm is not defined for any negative inputs (or $0$ input, either).

Answer (score 1):

This is because $\log x $ is a continuous function.

Let $f(x)$ be continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ . Suppose ${x_n} \in [a,b]$ is a sequence that converges to $x$ and $x \in [a,b]$ .

We will show that ${f(x_n)}$ converges to $f(x)$ .

Consider $|f(x_n) - f(x)|$ . We know that $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ , therefore it is continuous at $x\in [a,b]$ so for some arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta > 0 $ such that if $|y-x| < \delta$ , $|f(y) - f(x)|<\epsilon $.

Now, we know that ${x_n}$ converges to $x$ . Therefore, given $n> M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{N}$ we know that $|x_n - x| < \delta $ . The $\delta$ we are talking about here is the same one mentioned in the paragraph above.

Therefore, as $f(x)$ is continuous at $x$, we know that $|f(x_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $n>M$.

But since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, by the definition of convergence of a sequence, we can say that ${f(x_n)}$ truly converges to $f(x)$.

So your example, was this result, but with $f(x) = \log x$

You must also note that this only works if ${x_n}$ is a sequence that is positive for sufficiently large $n$, and thus converges to a positive number $x$. This is because $\log x$ is not defined for $x<0$ and is not continuous at $x=0$ , although we can fix this by using $log|x|$ instead, in which case we just need to make sure the sequence ${x_n}$ doesn't converge to $0$, as $log|x|$ is discontinuous there, so the theorem I have just proved does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

this is because $log_y$ is continue.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to show that the $\log_y$ function is continuous, because then it preserves the limits of sequences. Why is it continuous? You can show that its derivative is $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x \log(y)}$, so it's differentiable. Differentiable functions are continuous.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer but is it possible to show that $|\log_{y}{x_n} - \log_{y}{x}| < \epsilon$ for each $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: Yes. Avoid doing that if there's an easier way, but it is certainly possible. Use $\log x - \log y = \log \frac{x}{y}$.

Comment: Yeah but there's a problem. I can't say that $\log{\frac{x_n}{x}} = \log{1}$ because if I did that I would you use my claim.

Comment: You don't need equality, you just need equality in the limit. Take $\exp$ of both sides, splitting into the cases $x_n \geq x$ and $x_n < x$. You should say in the OP that it's necessary for you to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, by the way, because it's very much not the best way to do it.